# MaterializeCSS - aligning button and input field

Tags: materialize

With [materializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/) I'm trying to place a button and a input field one near to the other (similar to [default file input](http://materializecss.com/forms.html#file)) as shown in the image below.

[image: what I need]

But I have an hard time achieving it because the input field label is above the button or the field is below the button.

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m4 l3">
      <div class="file-field input-field">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large" type="submit" name="action">Button
        </button>
        <div class="file-path-wrapper">
          <input id="email_input" type="text">
          <label for="email_input">email</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rxKbZz

Is there a way to achieve it?

THANK YOU

Answer (score 5):

In 2017 Align input text and button on its right code:

```
<div class="row">
   <form class="col s12">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="input-field col s6">
               <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
               <label for="name">Name</label>
           </div>
           <div class="input-field col s6">
               <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Go!
               </button>
           </div>
       </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xzchwoae/)

Hope it works!

Answer (score 2):

just add the "input-field" class to your inputs and button containers

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
<div class="input-field inline" style="calc(100% - 100px)">
    <label>Código de Barras</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="">
</div>
<a class="btn waves-effect waves-light indigo right">
     <i class="material-icons">camera_alt</i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem but it got solved for me by adding a `<br>` tag just between input and button.

Answer (score 0):

Nice Code.

```
<div class="row">
                                    <form class="col s12">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l3 offset-l4">
                                                <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
                                                <label for="name" class="white-text">Busque número de pagina...</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-field col s12 m4 l1">
                                                <button class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light grey darken-4" type="submit"><i class="material-icons">search</i>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Not much different from David Corral's answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Button float in Input v:

```
<div class="row">
                                    <div class="input-field col l4 offset-l4">
                                        <input type="text" name="txtBusPag" id="txtBusPag" class="yellow-text"/>
                                        <label for="txtBusPag" class="white-text lighten-5"><button type="submit" class="btn-small grey darken-4 waves-effect waves-teal white-text"><i class="material-icons">search</i></button></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: please reformat your answer for readability, and please remove one of your two answers on this question

Answer (score -1):

this works for me in material:

```js
<div class="filters" layout="row" layout-align="center center">
 <md-input-container layout="row">
          <label>Enter Search Term!</label>
          <input type="text">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container>
          <label>Category</label>
          <md-select ng-model="category">
            <md-option>
    something
   </md-option>
          </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
    <div layout="row">
          <md-button class="md-warn">
              Clear
          </md-button>
    </div>
</div>
```